# How to set environment variable for another user?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

On Windows, how do I set an environment variable for a user other than the currently logged in one? I need to set the `TMP` variable to change the temporary directory used by an ASP.NET app.

Comment: As an unrelated comment: Why in the world would an ASP.NET application look to the computers Env. variables for a file path setting? AppSettings are built-in for that reason alone.

Comment: Also, this question is off topic for ServerFault, it should be posted on SuperUser

Comment: @BrentPabst - The standard temp directory api in .Net reads from it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx

Comment: Right, so what user is your application running under? Does it change that context each time a user logs in? Typically in IIS this is not the logged in user.

Comment: @BrentPabst - I don't get what you're getting at. It runs under the same context every time (Network Service). But rather than setting the TMP variable for the entire server, I want to set it just for that user. I think what uSlackr recommends is going to work. Are you proposing another approach?

Comment: @BrentPabst 5 years later, [ASP.NET Core reads the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) to determine the environment it is running in.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can access through the registry.  Modify the `\Environment\Tmp` key in `HKEY_Users\<their SID>`

Here are two solutions for getting the account SID

```
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domainname", "username") 
$SID = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
$SID.Value
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Filter "name = 'username' AND domain = 'domainname'"
```

Comment: Inspired by this answer, [I was able to figure out how to do this via Chef](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28224034/173497).

Comment: Is there an elegant way to get the SID of a user?. Particularly a virtual account?.

Comment: You could ask that as another question, but if you do a google search for `get sid of application pool identity`, the first result, http://winterdom.com/2014/05/iis-apppool-identity-sids, has a pretty elegant solution.

Comment: @austinian That link is now unavailable. That's why it's important to include such information in an answer itself, instead of linking to it.

Comment: This powershell code will grab the SID
`$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain", "username") 
$SID = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
$SID.Value`

or  `Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Filter "name = 'user' AND domain = 'domain'"`

Comment: The above is 3 separate lines starting with $. The last line can either be $SID.Value or Get-WmiObject. Thanks uSlackr, my SID's key (folder) wasn't created yet in Windows' regedit -- I really didn't want to log into it, but by editing my other account's temporary variables via My Computer -> Environmental Variables -> User Variables I was able to get Windows to automatically create the other account's key.

Comment: @Stijn no its still available:  http://web.archive.org/web/20160405211944/https://winterdom.com/2014/05/iis-apppool-identity-sids

Comment: I added SID catching code to the answer ...